# Zoom with animation in current location when map loads in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have used map in my view controller but when the maps loads it shows me view of the whole country. I want to show my current location view when maps loads, for that I have used `didUpdateUserLocation` method and set delegate for it.

My code is this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
   [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(_userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1f, 0.1f)) animated:YES];
}
```

Now when my map loads it animate and zoom but in wrong location. It is taking me to any location in sea when map loads , but my current location is different.

I have also tested it in real device but it does not show my location.

The maps looks like that when loads:

[image]

ViewController class code:

```
@property BOOL updateUserLocation;
@property(strong,nonatomic) CLLocation *userLocation;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *latitude;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *longitude;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
_AlertView.hidden=YES;
_distanceView.hidden=YES;
self.mapView.zoomEnabled=YES;

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];

}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(_userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1f, 0.1f)) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: 1 - Have you checked to see what values are in your latitude and longitude? (Or you are in the ocean?)

2 - Have you set the delegate to the mapView? `self.mapView.delegate = self;`

3 - Have you accepted the permission?

Comment: Yes i have all the above three. @Kerberos

Comment: the lat and the long are right?

Comment: i have given the userlocation.coordinate it should take it. @Kerberos

Comment: It should.. add a breakpoint in the method or add a NSLog to read the lat and the long and if you use the simulator use a location under the debug menu

Comment: i have used Apple location in simulator but still not going there.@Kerberos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines in the viewDidLoad:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

if you want to center the map to the user location add this:

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

**EDIT:**

ViewController example:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *location;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self mapView] setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // we have to setup the location manager with permission in later iOS versions
    if ([[self locationManager] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [[self locationManager] requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [[self locationManager] setDelegate:self];
    [[self locationManager] setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // Stop updating location, when you want to restart update use [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

    self.location = locations.lastObject;

    // zoom the map into the users current location
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
        (self.location.coordinate, 2, 2);
    [[self mapView] setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I've only added the IBOutlet on the storyboard and the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in the plist.

If you change the location on the simulator you can see the maps change location.

If you want I can upload the complete example project.

**NEW EDIT:**

There is an error in you code!

When you use `[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(_userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1f, 0.1f)) animated:YES]`, you use _userLocation that is your `CLLocation` variable! You must use userLocation that is the value that you receive from the method.

I recommend you to change the CCLocation variable name and use the userLocation name only for the variable used in the didUpdateUserLocation method.

Comment: let me try. @Kerberos

Comment: bro its not working , its again taking me to the sea. Can u plz check my class? @Kerberos

Comment: Yep, upload the class or edit your answer with the class code.

Comment: Bro can u give ur email id i can send u there. @Kerberos

Comment: Use something like dropbox or google drive to upload the project so all we can help you.

Comment: i have added code check it in my question. @Kerberos

Comment: have u seen it? @Kerberos

Comment: let me check it. @Kerberos

Comment: Bro , how can i check it in my simulator. @Kerberos

Comment: Start the simulator and then on the top menu bar select Debug->Location-> and select one of the location.

Comment: Bro i have done it but again taking me to the sea when loads. @Kerberos

Comment: Can you upload your project?

Comment: should i check it in real device? @Kerberos

Comment: Yep, you can deploy it in an iPhone.

Comment: i cn give u please send me ur email. @Kerberos

Comment: I'm testing in real device . Bro can i give CLLocation as my self.mapView.userLcoation.coordinate? @Kerberos

Comment: You can use your code and simply remove the underscore ( _ ) on the _userLocation variable.
So with userLocation you use the variable of the method and not yours.

Comment: Then in the didUpdateUserLocation you can save the coordinates with: self.userLocation = userLocation.coordinate;
But I recommend to change your variable name.

Comment: Bro when i use ur code of CLLocation it takes me to the location but an issue occurs that maps don't move anywhere it only shows the current location , and when i replace ur code with mine like this CLLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location; . It takes me to the sea. Why it isn't catching the user location coordinate? @Kerberos

Comment: When you see the ocean is because the location coordinate is 0,0.
Please, revert all to your original code and add this line into the method: `[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1f, 0.1f)) animated:YES];`

Comment: In my code is right that it return to the user location, you can discard the setRegion if the userLocation is the same of the new location.

Comment: @siddle I've edited the viewController sample code, now you can move the map, only when the user move it returns to the map. If you want to only display the first time you can stop update location with  [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

Comment: Bro , i have reverted all the code and use ur line of code and than stopUpdating Location now working fine, plz change ur answer with that so that i could mark it right. @Kerberos

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method and zoom on map

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = ; // your latitude value
        zoomLocation.longitude=  // your longitude value
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.18; // change as per your zoom level
    span.longitudeDelta=0.18;
    region.span=span;
    region.center= zoomLocation;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapview regionThatFits:region];
```

Comment: @siddle when you get the location of user you can call this method

Answer (score 0):

Use `didUpdateToLocation` instead of `didUpdateUserLocation`.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
    region.center.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

See also my library.

https://github.com/koogawa/KGWLocationPicker/blob/master/KGWLocationPicker/KGWLocationPickerViewController.m